# Java 8 Stream optimization

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, java-stream, simplify

I have a below code base which is using to to find any matching object and its status failure,What is the most simplified way of implementing below code

```
DummyCounter dummyCounter=new DummyCounter();
dummyCounter.setDue("DONE");
dummyCounter.setStatus(1);

DummyCounter dummyCounte1=new DummyCounter();
dummyCounte1.setDue("FAILRUE");
dummyCounte1.setStatus(1);

DummyCounter dummyCounte2=new DummyCounter();
dummyCounte2.setDue("DONE");
dummyCounte2.setStatus(1);

List<DummyCounter>  counterList=new ArrayList<DummyCounter>();
counterList.add(dummyCounter);
counterList.add(dummyCounte2);
counterList.add(dummyCounte2);
```

Usage

```
final Integer integer = counterList.stream()
       .filter(customer -> "DONE".equals(customer.getDue()))
       .map(DummyCounter::getStatus)
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .findAny()
       .get();

System.out.println(integer);
```

Comment: I don't see the need of `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` ... at least from your example

Comment: The status is always set  to `1` in this exemple

Comment: You'd be better off using an `enum` for due, instead of a `String`. That would potentially save you from typos like "FAILRUE"...

Answer (score 0):

To find all failed entries you may do like below:

```
List<DummyCounter> failedDummies = counterList.stream()
      .filter(dummy-> "FAILURE".equals(dummy.getDue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to find failed count:

```
int totalFailedCounters = counterList.stream()
          .filter(dummy-> "FAILURE".equals(dummy.getDue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList()).size();
```